# Using Analog Pins for Power

Tags: arduino-uno, power, analog

I'd like to power something needing 5V DC using the Arduino Uno analog pins. Specifically, I'm following the "Fun Plug-in Hack for Arduino UNO" section of [this Adafruit tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/ds1307-real-time-clock-breakout-board-kit/wiring-it-up). It states:

> "If you set analog pin A3 to an OUTPUT and HIGH and A2 to an OUTPUT
> and LOW you can power the RTC directly from the pins!"

It doesn't seem to work, so I try this with a multimeter hooked up to A2 & A3:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(A2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A3, OUTPUT);
  analogWrite(A2, LOW);
  analogWrite(A3, HIGH);
}

void loop() {}
```

I only measure ~0.8V, trying 2 boards including a brand-new unboxed one. This is the same whether the board is powered via USB or via 9V battery in the barrel jack.

But I *can* measure ~5V from those pins if I set the "ground" pin as INPUT_PULLUP (using the built-in pull-up resistor) instead of OUTPUT:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(A2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(A3, OUTPUT);
  analogWrite(A3, HIGH);
}

void loop() {}
```

I don't believe Adafruit is wrong, since conceptually it makes more sense to set both pins to OUTPUT, with one being HIGH and the other being LOW. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What were you trying to power?

Comment: @Majenko DS1307 RTC

Answer (score 2):

The analog pins are only analog *inputs* but *digital* outputs (and inputs too). You use `digitalWrite()` to control a pin's HIGH or LOW state.

`ànalogWrite()` is for use with the PWM pins (I hate the name the chose for that function it's so wrong on so many levels).

Also this powering trick only works for things that need very small currents (< about 20mA) since that is the maximum an IO pin can deliver.

---

Incidentally, you *can* use `analogWrite()` on a non-PWM pin, but it's either fully on (analog value >= 127) or fully off (analog value < 127). The macros HIGH and LOW are 1 and 0 respectively, so that equates to "fully off" and "fully off" on a plain non-PWM pin.